# Facebook API and pagination

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have code that should be getting and pulling a query, and it does that successfully. However, when I go to the next field, there is an address there, but if i use requests.get('address') nothing comes up. But if I go to the address manually all the data is clearly there.

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=token)
users = graph.request('/search?q=Donald Trump&type=event')
print(users['paging']['next'])
hold = requests.get(users['paging']['next']).json()
```

hold just returns {data:[]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check that you are getting back enough items to cause it to page.  I suspect you get a next link even if you only get a few items and nothing to page to.

e.g. compare the next link for

/v2.10/search?q=Donald Trump&type=event&limit=50

vs

/v2.10/search?q=Donald Trump&type=event&limit=2